# Not getting total response from http client in windows universal app in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

Hi,
             I am migrating windows phone 8.1 app to windows universal app .I have used HttpClient in windows phone 8.1 that works fine.If I use the same in uap I am able to hit the server and get the response but the response I am getting is incomplete some part of the json is missing.I don't what is happening can any one suggest me the right way.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = url.Host;

response = await httpClient.GetAsync(mypresurl);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Stream receive = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receive, Encoding.UTF8);
    string parseString = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Some part of the json is missing in response.

Comment: So the parseString is does not hold the complete data during debug?

Comment: What does a debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com) show is transferred over the wire?

Comment: Do you have the same behavior with response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below code? I am using the same and each response contains proper json.

```
private async void getJson()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("YOUR URL HERE");
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = url.Host;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
        if(response!=null)
        {
            //Here is your json retrieved:
            var resposneJson = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
```